# for loop range outside a sliding window

Tags: python, list, for-loop, pyspark

I have a range in a list(100 strings). I want to iterate a number of times (say 4 times) over this range by selecting 30 strings at a given interval and store them in a list. But I also want to store the selections outside the 30 strings and store them in a different list using pyspark.

Assuime the integers in the lists below are strings, Example code:

```
t=[]
start=[10,20,50,70]
for i in start:
    windoww=i+30
    for j in range(i,windoww):
        t.append(j)
```

The above code gets me a list `t` ranging 10 to 99 with the start string specified in `start`.
I also want a list that is outside `t`. So for the first iteration if the content of `t` is

```
t= [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]
```

I want another list say `u` that has

```
u=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
```

Is this possible in pyspark?

I tried creating a list from [0 to 100] called `v` and did:

```
u=[stri for stri in v not in t]
```

However, I get an error that

> 'bool' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try below function**

```
def Diff(li1, li2):
    return (list(list(set(li1)-set(li2)) + list(set(li2)-set(li1))))
 
li1 = [10, 15, 20]
li2 = [20, 15, 35]
  
li3 = Diff(li1, li2)
print(li3)

Output = [10,35]
```